# How can I make a node to be of multiple types?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm doing a test movie project to learn neo4j and SDN and here is a problem I'm facing:
As you know movie director may be a producer or a writer or even an actor. In my **java** class architecture I have *Person* superclass. And it has children: *Producer, Director, Actor* and *Writer*. All these children nodes are on the same level, thus they are incompatible types.
While on the other hand, in **neo4j** I have nodes that are at the same time Producer, Director and Writer. 
[image: example of node that has several labels]
So I have a problem when I want to get all directors via repository.findAll() method (or via custom method with Cypher query). Spring tells me:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Set field
>   com.test.db.domain.Producer.producedMovies to
>   com.test.db.domain.Director

I use Neo4j 2.0.1 and Spring Data Neo4j 3.0.0.RELEASE.

What is the right way to solve such kind of issue?

---

Update:
Here is the code:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("service-beans.xml");
        Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate = context.getBean(Neo4jTemplate.class);

        DirectorRepository repository = context.getBean(DirectorRepository.class);
        try (Transaction transaction = neo4jTemplate.getGraphDatabase().beginTx()) {
            EndResult<Director> all = repository.findAll_Upd(); //repository.findAll();
            Iterator<Director> iterator = all.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
            transaction.success();
        }
    }
}

@Transactional
public interface DirectorRepository extends GraphRepository<Director> {
    @Query("match(n:Director) return n")
    EndResult<Director> findAll_Upd();
}

@NodeEntity
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    @GraphId
    Long nodeId;
//    @Indexed(unique=true)
    String id;
    @Indexed(indexType= IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "people")
    String name;
    private Short born;
    private Date birthday;
    private String birthplace;
    private String biography;
    private Integer version;
    private Date lastModified;
    private String profileImageUrl;
...
}

public class Director extends Person {
    @Fetch @RelatedTo(elementClass = Movie.class, type = RelationshipConstants.DIRECTED)
    private Set<Movie> directedMovies = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Producer extends Person {
    @Fetch @RelatedTo(elementClass = Movie.class, type = RelationshipConstants.PRODUCED)
    private Set<Movie> producedMovies = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Actor extends Person  {
    @RelatedToVia(type = RelationshipConstants.ACTED_IN)
    List<Role> roles;
}

@NodeEntity
public class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {
    @GraphId
    Long nodeId;    
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    String id;    
    @Indexed(indexType= IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "search")
    String title;    
    int released;    
    String tagline;    
    @Fetch @RelatedTo(type = RelationshipConstants.ACTED_IN, direction = INCOMING)
    Set<Actor> actors;    
    @Fetch @RelatedTo(type = RelationshipConstants.PRODUCED, direction = INCOMING)
    Set<Producer> producers;    
    @RelatedToVia(type = RelationshipConstants.ACTED_IN, direction = INCOMING)
    List<Role> roles;
}
```

And the full Exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Setting
>   property producedMovies to null on Rob Reiner [null]  at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.setProperty(SourceStateTransmitter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$2.doWithAssociation(SourceStateTransmitter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesFrom(SourceStateTransmitter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityFetchHandler.fetchValue(Neo4jEntityFetchHandler.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityFetchHandler.fetch(Neo4jEntityFetchHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl$1.doWithAssociation(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.cascadeFetch(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.loadEntity(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.createEntityFromState(Neo4jTemplate.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.createEntitySetFromRelationshipEndNodes(RelationshipHelper.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToFieldAccessor.createEntitySetFromRelationshipEndNodes(RelatedToFieldAccessor.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessor.getValue(RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.getValue(DefaultEntityState.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyEntityStatePropertyValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$000(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$2.doWithAssociation(SourceStateTransmitter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesFrom(SourceStateTransmitter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.loadEntity(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:112)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.read(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.read(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.createEntityFromState(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.projectTo(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:216)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.projectTo(Neo4jTemplate.java:240)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.doConvert(EntityResultConverter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.convert(DefaultConverter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.convert(EntityResultConverter.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1.convert(QueryResultBuilder.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1.access$300(QueryResultBuilder.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1$1.underlyingObjectToObject(QueryResultBuilder.java:121)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
>     at com.test.util.App.main(App.java:34)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   java.util.Set field com.test.db.domain.Producer.producedMovies to
>   com.test.db.domain.Director   at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)  at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.setField(ReflectionUtils.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.setProperty(BeanWrapper.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.setProperty(BeanWrapper.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.setProperty(SourceStateTransmitter.java:83)
>     ... 43 more

---

Update 
I have also tried projectTo () method ([projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#reference:programming-model:projection)), but still I get the same exception:

```java
Director director = neo4jTemplate.projectTo(person, Director.class);
```

Comment: can you share the code of your classes? Can you upgrade to SDN 3.0.1 ? And the full exception?

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for a fast reply. I've added code and exception into the description. I've also upgraded to SDN 3.0.1, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the neo4j mapping - but your java model doesn't match your business description - you more need a Person class with a Set < MovieJob> member- where MovieJob is your abstract class which Actor, Director, Producer are subclasses.

Comment: Nice observation, Dan. But this hierarchy was mainly copied from cineasts example [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples/cineasts/src/main/java/org/neo4j/cineasts/domain) and since for me it's just a test of neo4j and spring data I have not bothered much about the java model.